# Null controller when test with Mockito

Tags: testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm testing a controller that needs a Autowired Service.

I read in many place (example [Mockito: How to test my Service with mocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288386/mockito-how-to-test-my-service-with-mocking)) I need to do it like this

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class AdminControllerTest {

  @Mock
  private AdminService service;

  @InjectMocks
  private AdminController adminController;

  @Test
  public void registerUser() {
    Boolean resultReal = adminController.registerUser();
    assertTrue(resultReal);
  }
}
```

But it's fail and I see is because the adminController is null

Instead, if I create the controller like this

```
AdminController adminController = new AdminController();
```

It works, but then I can inject the mock.

Maybe I'm forgotten something

Comment: show the controller definition and include injected dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation for InjectMocks](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html):

> MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this) method has to be called to initialize annotated objects. In above example, openMocks() is called in @Before (JUnit4) method of test's base class. For JUnit3 openMocks() can go to setup() method of a base class. Instead you can also put openMocks() in your JUnit runner (@RunWith) or use the built-in MockitoJUnitRunner.

Thus, either:

1. call `openMocks(this)` somewhere before the test is run or
2. Use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` on the class